# Ошибка во время компиляции, как исправить?

Tags: unity3d, android-sdk, java

```
jdk-9.0.4_windows-x64_bin
Android Studio 3.1
```

*Console:*

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to list target platforms. Please make sure the android sdk path is correct. See the Console for more details. 
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-9.0.4\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="C:/Users/ivank/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar" -

stderr[
Error:Invalid command android
]
stdout[

]
exit code: 64
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

- Убедитесь, что правильно указали путь на sdk.
- Убедитесь, что указали путь на jdk  в параметрах Unity.
- Убедитесь, что у вас прописаны   параметры среды - JAVA_HOME.

Для более подробной описании ошибки - попробуйте вручную, через консоль получить список установленных у вас платформ (команда отображается в дебаг консоли).